# Sequential Sheet References

Tags: excel, excel-formula, reference, cell

I'm trying to create a calendar that references specific cells from another sheet.
For example, the first calendar entry is Sheet1!$A$3.

I need the next reference to be 4 cells down from the previous (Sheet1!$A$7), and so on (next being Sheet1!$A$7).

Is there a formula that will check the previous cell reference and return the value 4 cells below the previous?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on ***Microsoft-365*** then can try-

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,SEQUENCE(10,1,3,4))
```

Otherwise can try-

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,(ROW(1:1)*4)-1)
```

Comment: Unfrotunately that won't work with the calendar formatting I have.  The first cell reference (=Sheet1!$A$3 is in cell D4 on the calendar sheet.  The next reference would need to be in call F4, which is why something that references the initial cell call seems ideal.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether D4 contains the text string "Sheet1!$A$3" or if it contains the *contents* of cell A3 on Sheet1.  If it contains the contents it's of no use to the formula in cell D5.  However, if it's the string "Sheet1!$A$3" then we can do some interesting things, especially if you have Excel O365, so that you have the new TEXT family of array functions.